# regex -- split one column into multiple columns with no explicit delimiters in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a column in my data set called "Market.Pair" that contains information about departure and destination points of some flights. For example:

```
input <- data.frame(Market.Pair = c("US to/from CA", "HOU to/from DFW/DAL", "EWR/JFK to/from LAX/SFO", "US-NYC to/from FR-PAR", "US to/from Asia"))
input
```

All two letter words represent countries(ex. US, CA).
All three letter words(or multiple three letter words separated by "/") represent airports(ex. HOU, DFW/DAL).
All words in the form of XX-XXX represent cities (ex. US-NYC).
Other words represent regions, such as Asia, or Europe.

I would like to split this column into multiple columns:

```
output<- data.frame(Air.1 = c("HOU", "EWR/JFK", "", "", ""), Air.2 = c("DFW/DAL", "LAX/SFO", "", "", ""), City.1 = c("","","US-NYC", "", ""), City.2 = c("","","FR-PAR", "", ""), Country.1 = c("","","","US", "US"), Coutry.2 = c("","","","CA", ""), Region.1 = c("","","", "", "Asia"), Region.2 = c("","","", "", ""))
output
```

I am new to regex, so any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: @rawr I used strsplit to split "Market.Pair" into two columns: "Departure" and "Destination". And like I said, I am extremely new to regex, so I looked at some other posts, and tried this command: grep('\b\w{3}\b', input$Departure) to try to find the departing airports, but didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input <- data.frame(Market.Pair = c("US to/from CA", "HOU to/from DFW/DAL",
                                    "EWR/JFK to/from LAX/SFO", "US-NYC to/from FR-PAR",
                                    "US to EMEA/India"))

sp <- strsplit(as.character(input$Market.Pair), '\\s+to(/from)?\\s+')

f <- Vectorize(function(x)
  if (grepl('\\-', x)) 'City' else if (nchar(x) == 2) 'Country' else
    if (grepl('^[A-Z]+/[A-Z]+$|^[A-Z]+$', x)) 'Air' else 'Region')

dd <- lapply(sp, function(x) {
  ## set up output matrix
  cn <- sort(levels(interaction(c('Air','City','Country','Region'), 1:2)))
  m <- matrix('', 1, length(cn), dimnames = list(NULL, cn))
  ## use f above and add the suffix
  xx <- f(x)
  nn <- setNames(x, paste(xx, ave(xx, xx, FUN = seq_along), sep = '.'))
  ## match
  m[, names(nn)] <- nn
  m
})
do.call('rbind.data.frame', dd)

#     Air.1   Air.2 City.1 City.2 Country.1 Country.2   Region.1 Region.2
# 1                                      US        CA                    
# 2     HOU DFW/DAL                                                      
# 3 EWR/JFK LAX/SFO                                                      
# 4                 US-NYC FR-PAR                                        
# 5                                      US           EMEA/India
```

Comment: Hi rawr, thanks for the answer! Could you please refer to the comment I left at the first answer; I added some more information on the problem at hand. In my understanding, they should only affect the strsplit and Vectorize command in your codes, but I am not sure exactly how to modify them. Thanks again!

Comment: It's odd that the other answer disappeared.. Anyways I added two things: firstly, in Market.Pair, some entries have "to" instead of "to/from", how will this affect the strsplit command? Secondly, airports are not the only ones with "/". Some regions, such as "Latin America/Mexico" and "EMEA/India" also have "/". How should the Vectorize command be modified then? Thanks!

Comment: It worked like a charm! One last question though, in Market.Pair, there are rare cases of entries like this: "EWR to HKG/NRT, JFK to HKG". I would like to turn the parts before and after the "," into two separate rows. How can I incorporate that into your existing codes?

Comment: @JJ.Y are those completely separate entries? since you're just basically working with a vector, you could select Market.Pair and `unlist(strsplit(input$Market.Pair, ',\\s+'))` which will return a vector but with the ones containing commas split in two

Comment: Are you suggesting that I split the string first by commas, then split the result again by "to"|"to/from"? Something like this: strsplit(as.character(unlist(strsplit(input$Market.Pair, ',\\s+'))), '\\s+to(/from)?\\s+') ?

Comment: @JJ.Y you don't have to do it all in one go `x <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(input$Market.Pair), ',\\s+')); sp <- strsplit(x, '\\s+to(/from)?\\s+')` and then the `dd <- lapply(...`

Comment: @rawr It worked! Thank so much for all your help! This is my first time asking questions on stackoveflow, and it's been terrific!

Comment: @AnandaMahto This is my first time learning about the splitstackshape package(I am pretty new to R), but I think it's really cool. I will definitely look into it! I am gonna choose rawr's answer this time, just because he answered all my questions first, but your contribution is much appreciated!

Comment: Hi there, I have an update on the question and hope you could so generously offer some help again. The new request is that destinations must be in the xxx.2 columns. The current code works just fine if it's a air-air or city-city pair, but when it's, for example, air-city pair, it assigned the destination to city.1 instead of city.2. I figure this would involve some changes in the ave() function, but couldn't figure out how. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @JJ.Y I assumed the 1,2 was like a running count of the type. if you want 1 for departure and 2 for destination, since the arrival is always first, couldn't you just replace the `nn <-` line with `nn <- setNames(x, paste(xx, 1:2, sep = '.'))`? that seems simpler than using `ave`

Answer (score 4):

Here's a fairly manual approach, but it should still be quite efficient. It uses `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package to split the columns, then it subsets by condition using "data.table" to create new values by reference. Finally, it uses `dcast` (again from "data.table") to go into the wide format.

Here's some new sample data with the conditions you describe in your comment.

```
input <- data.frame(
  Market.Pair = c(
    "US to/from CA", "HOU to/from DFW/DAL",            # Your sample data
    "EWR/JFK to/from LAX/SFO", 
    "US-NYC to/from FR-PAR", "US to/from Asia", 
    "Latin America/Mexico to EMEA/India",              # Some only "to", exception to "/"
    "EWR to HKG/NRT, JFK to HKG"))                     # Some > 1 pair of values per row
```

Here's a possible approach:

```
library(splitstackshape)
## First, take care of data combined in single rows
x <- cSplit(input, "Market.Pair", ",", "long")

## Add indicator for row names
x[, rn := 1:nrow(x)]

## Split on to/from or to
x <- cSplit(x, "Market.Pair", " to/from | to ", "long", fixed = FALSE, 
            stripWhite = FALSE, type.convert = FALSE)

## Add a column named "type" filled with 'Region' as the value
x[, type := "Region"]

## Using your defined conditions, you can replace the values in the
##   'type' column by reference. Here's 'Air'...
x[nchar(Market.Pair) == 3 | grepl("^.../...$", Market.Pair), type := "Air"]

## ... here's 'Country'
x[nchar(Market.Pair) == 2, type := "Country"]

## ... and here's 'City'
x[grepl("^..-...$", Market.Pair), type := "City"]

## Add an indicator variable...
x[, ind := sequence(.N), by = .(rn, type)]
```

Now, you can reshape the data to a wide format using `dcast` from "data.table"

```
dcast(x, rn ~ type + ind, value.var = "Market.Pair", fill = "")
#    rn   Air_1   Air_2 City_1 City_2 Country_1 Country_2             Region_1   Region_2
# 1:  1                                      US        CA                                
# 2:  2     HOU DFW/DAL                                                                  
# 3:  3 EWR/JFK LAX/SFO                                                                  
# 4:  4                 US-NYC FR-PAR                                                    
# 5:  5                                      US                           Asia           
# 6:  6                                                   Latin America/Mexico EMEA/India
# 7:  7     EWR HKG/NRT                                                                  
# 8:  8     JFK     HKG
```

Comment: Hi Ananda, thanks so much for your answer! It looks like it's gonna work, but I did omit two little things in my example to simplify it, so if you could show me how to modify your existing codes to accommodate those changes that would be great! Firstly, in Market.Pair, some entries have "to" instead of "to/from", how should the cSplit command be modified? Secondly, airports are not the only places that might contain "/". Some regions, such as "Latin America/Mexico", and "EMEA/India" also contain slash. How do we distinguish airports now? Again thanks so much for your help!